# Not able to Authorize an ORG in VS Code

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcedx, ide, vs-code, editor

I am trying to create project workspace using VS Code. I am using SFDX: Create Project with Manifest command. After executing, it is creating folder for my project with all default files in VS code. But when I am trying to Authorize an Org, I don't see that command in the palette. 
I tried all ways. Like uninstalling everything including CLI but it is not working. 
Please advise. 
[image]

Comment: What java version you have. Is your classpath shows sfdx?  are you able to run the authorization from the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

seems like extensions are not active for your org install the tools required then try again it will work.

Comment: Hi Akash, thank you for your message. I can see 'No Default Org set' at the bottom left but whenever I am trying to authorize an Org by doing CTRL + SHIFT+ P , it does not show me option to authorize an org. I have added a snapshot in my original question.

Comment: Try to update the java min- 8 is required.
Hope it helps.

Comment: add the update JDK  path in salesforce: apex

Answer (score 0):

Run this command : # **sfdx update**
after that you will see Authorize an Org appear in your vs code palette
*That worked for me ;)*

Answer (score -1):

You will not see the option to authorize the org when your extension does not activate when you open the VS Code.

The below pic shows only three options when I open the command palette. When you see the blue bar at bottom in left, it does not shows you weather you are authorized to an org or not.
[image]

In the below pic, It does not give me the option to deploy components to org or retrieve it from org because extensions are not activated.

[image]

This pic shows extensions are getting activated if you focus on the blue bar at the bottom in left.

[image]

Once extensions are activated, I got the option to authorize an org. Generally, it takes a few minutes for auto-activation.
[image]

Comment: Hi Sanket, thank you for your message. I can see 'No Default Org set' at the bottom left but whenever I am trying to authorize an Org by doing CTRL + SHIFT+ P , it does not show me option to authorize an org. I have added a snapshot in my original question.